# how to get all latitudes and longitudes from google map given two locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

i am developing an android application that performs route matching , i have a problem on how to get set of all latitudes and longitudes  for a given path provided source location and destination location 

For example, i have given delhi as source location and bangalore as destination location , on calling the google directions api with source and destination locations latitude and longitude  it draws a path by taking some way points (say some 100)  but i want all the latitudes and longitudes in that path for every 100 metre distance.
 
Please drive me to solve this problem

Comment: Since you have the two locations, the to and from locations, why not increment or decrement each locations lat and long until it reaches one another? For example: Location 1 lat: 100, Location 2 lat: 200, while(lat1 != lat 2) -> increment/decrement lat1 and store that value.  Apply the same logic for longitude.

Comment: yes we can add but on which direction should i add, suppose i have lat 11.2343 and the destination lat is 25.658 which is in north side(suppose) . if i want to increment on which direction should i increment

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you are creating a **rectangle**.

Let's say the rectangle is 7 wide with the center point being the lower of the two lats.

This will give you *ALL* of the locations between the two points that are 7 wide. Look at the following image which illustrates this:

[image]

Algorithm:

1. Start at the top left
2. Increment the long until you reach the end
3. Increment the Lat and Reset the Long back to the beginning
4. Repeat 2 and 3 until you reach the end and record all of the locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ready made functions, you may include the [SphericalUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html) into your project. With that you can easily compute the distance (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween) and heading (SphericalUtil.computeHeading) between 2 points and afterwards move (SphericalUtil.computeOffset) the first point again and again by 100 meter into the direction given by the heading until the full distance is reached.

Comment: @Manikanta What exactly is it, you do not understand? I will try to answer of course. But I think the coding part should still be yours. SO is no platform for asking for readymade copy&paste snippets for any simple coding task.

Comment: thank you very much !! almost i was at the wedge of solving this problem. i will ask you if there are any !

Comment: not working its just drawing a straight line not  considering the curves in road

Comment: That's exactly what I expected, and I already wondered, why you want to have the additional points. But now it gets clear, what you really want. Without any further knowledge of the route, I see no chance to find intermediate points which are lying on the route. I never used google directions API. Maybe there is an option to get more accurate routes. I do not see any other way, as the information of the map itself (streets etc.) is totally hidden.

Comment: anyway thanks for your contribution and by the way one thing i was clear is google gives routes with only 8 waypoints !!!! more than that it is not possible and badly  if we want, we need to pay 10000$. expensive indeed